# Validation list creation, "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code yesterday and it worked absolutely fine, now for some reason it it throwing up Run-time error '1004'

The first part iterates through entries on a second sheet and, when certain conditions are satisfied, uses information from the second sheet to reference a third sheet to add an entry to an array. This array becomes pretty big, about 200 entries, I don't know what the limitations on an array are so this may be the source of my problem.

The second part takes that array and adds a validation list to the first sheet with that array as the dropdown list.

I've tried re-writing the code for the validation list in case I slipped up somehwere but haven't been able to spot a problem

The really weird thing is that this was working yesterday and nothing should have changed overnight.

Edit Note: sheet "A" is the active sheet, sheets "E" and "F" are in a separate workbook (yes this particular subroutine does reference 6 separate sheets), LAr() is previously defined as a string array

Edit 2 Note: Interestingly, other validation lists involving large arrays have started throwing up the same error in a different workbook. Does anyone know if there has been an update or something?

Edit 3 Note: it appears that excel was updated.

```
i = 1
k = 0
Do While E.Cells(i, 1) <> "" 'iterate until there are no more entries'
    ReDim Preserve LAr(0 To k) 'resize the array to take another value'
    If E.Cells(i, 4).Value = "YES" Then 'case where the item is chooseable and reference is a string of multiple row numbers'
        j = CInt(Split(E.Cells(i, 2).Value, ",")(0)) 'split off the first row number'
        LAr(k) = F.Cells(j, 2).Value 'add the item name to the array'
        k = k + 1 'increase the array entry counter by 1'
    ElseIf E.Cells(i, 4).Value = "NO" Then 'case where item is chooseable and reference is a single row number'
        j = E.Cells(i, 2).Value 'get the row number'
        LAr(k) = F.Cells(j, 2).Value 'add the item name to the array'
        k = k + 1 'increase the array entry counter by 1'
    ElseIf E.Cells(i, 4).Value = "" And E.Cells(i, 3).Value = "NO" Then 'case where the item is not chooseable and is not a header'
        j = E.Cells(i, 2).Value 'get the row number'
        LAr(k) = F.Cells(j, 2).Value 'add the item name to the array'
        k = k + 1 'increase the array entry counter by 1'
    End If
    i = i + 1 'increase the iteration counter by 1'
Loop

A.Cells(3, 7).Value = "Pick"
'create validation list with the array as the choices'
With A.Cells(3, 7).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(LAr, ",")
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = A.Cells(3, 7).Value
End With
```

I expect this to produce a validation list with the entries from the array, however, it currently gives error '1004'

Comment: The limit is 255 characters for a validation list string. You can usually assign more than that in code, but you'll have problems when you save and reopen the file. Far better to put the entries in a range somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Rory, the file never actually gets saved, it just writes and reads data from other files. The problem with putting the entries into a range is that there are abut 150 sets of strings that need to be made into arrays, the longest string has 69 entries. Interestingly, there was an update to ecel today, I've done some testing and it appears that the maximum number of entries I can store in an array is now 11 and the character length of the string that is being split into the array is 54.